# Node/Express access logger from request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, express

I am trying to see if there is a way to access my logger form a request object. I have a cusotm winston wrapper that uses winston, express-winston, and moment to keep things clean across my apps.

In my app.js I just have

```
  var logger = require('winston-custom');

  server.use(logger());
```

Then in the controller I am trying to find a clean way to get the logger off the request object (if possible), so I do not have to import it here. My first guess was it's on the req.app, but it does not appear to be.

so In a controller for the same server I have

```
 function rootAPI(req, res) {
  console.log("req.app", req.app);
```

Which seems to not provide me with anything, I even tried logging req and digging through it. Is there any way to correctly achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @dm03514 I can, I was asked to see if there is a way around this in passing it in the req object (if possible of course)

Comment: I mean, you could require it in your app and then in custom middleware attach it to the request, i just don't understand why you would do that instead of just requiring it.

Comment: @KevinB just requested to see if it could be done effectively, so just seeing if it's possible, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you need this functionality, you can achieve it by adding a custom field on `request`:

```
server.all("*", function(req, res, next)
{
    req.logger = logger;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

while the answer above is correct, we can simplify the implement by creating an express middleware:

```
const app = express()
const loggerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => { req.logger = logger; next()};
app.use(loggerMiddleware)
```

It is important that `next()` is called, else the next middleware wouldn't be called.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html